# How does the generate and test method work in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I need help understanding what the generate and test method in prolog is, what it is used for and how to use it. I've searched for answers online but can't really find an answer to my question.

Comment: Do a Google search on *prolog "generate and test"* to find lots of information. For example, the first hit on Google search is: [PROLOG Programming Methodology Generate & Test](http://gki.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/ws0708/logic/prolog9.pdf)